# How to merge multiple dataurl (pdf files) into one using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

**I have multiple pdf files.I just converted into a dataurl.Now I want to send all these pdf file dataurl into request.How to merge all these dataurl into one  by using js.**
major doubt is how to merge and download all pdf's by using merged single dataurl.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to send all the data, why not join all dataurl into one string?, something like:

```
const sFullDataUrl = sDataUrlPdf1 + '[separator]' + sDataUrlPdf2 + '[separator]' + [...];
```

Comment: sorry man !! i want to download all these pdf's  using single (merged) data url ! help me